# how could I relaunch mongodb service after killed by OOM

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

how could I relaunch mongodb service after killed by OOM

I couldn't find the reason why the mongodb service killed by OS about every 2 days.
is there any workaround to launch the mongodb service when it got killed

I've already set some system configs to avoid killing the mongodb service

thanks so much

## /etc/security/limits.conf

```
*         hard    nofile      unlimited
*         soft    nofile      unlimited
root      hard    nofile      unlimited
root      soft    nofile      unlimited
```

## /etc/sysctl.conf

vm.oom-kill = 0

vm.overcommit_memory = 1

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. Your machine has to be well under dimensioned for the task at hand. Can you state a bit more, like RAM (utilization), running processes and alike?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add these lines in `/etc/init/mongod.conf`

```
    respawn
    respawn limit 10 100
```

it will retry restart the service in 100 seconds